# Which PCA (or kernel PCA) basis better describes a single test sample?

Tags: classification, pca, kernel-trick

I have two PCA bases obtained by decomposition of two groups of training data. I also have some samples of test data. 
How can I decide which PCA basis fits better each test sample?

I tried to transform each sample to the PCA basis and measure the energy in the off diagonals in the resulting covariance matrix, but I don't think I can actually discuss covariance matrix derived from a single sample.

**Edit**

After helpful comments, I have the following revised question.

A good method for estimating which is better is to transform the new sample to each of the PCA spaces, truncate the coefficients, transform back and check the reconstruction error.

However, it appears to be more complex in KPCA. I can transform a new sample, $x_{new}$, to the KPCA basis, by introducing a vector $K_{new}=\phi(x_{new})^T\phi(y)$ for all $y$ used for creating the PCA basis and then performing PCA: $p_{new}=K_{new}V$ where $V$ are the eigenvectors for the KPCA.

But after truncating $p_{new}$, reverting back is difficult, since it is governed by the equation $p_{new}=K_{new}V$. It obviously cannot be simply inverted, and using pseudo-inverse for $V$ yields an ill-conditioned problem. Can this be done?

Comment: Usually you would be interested in just a few leading PCs, not the whole basis; then you can use reconstruction error of your test sample with each set of PCA axes (but if you use all axes, then reconstruction error is always zero).

Comment: @amoeba That sounds like a good answer ;-).

Comment: Thanks, @amoeba. That sounds reasonable. I think I might have to get more dimensions for the PCA, though.

Comment: Any idea on how to do this on Kernel PCA? now I can't use an "inverse" transform.

Comment: @ido: Yes, it would also work for kernel PCA. Actually, it makes your question more interesting (+1) and I will try to provide a answer later today or tomorrow.

Comment: I will edit my original question to better fit the current requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Standard PCA

Usually you would be interested in just several leading PCs, not the whole basis; then you can use reconstruction error of your test sample with each set of PCA axes to decide which set fits your test sample better (the lower the reconstruction error, the better the fit). If you use all PCA axes, then reconstruction error will always be zero, so comparison becomes meaningless.

"Several leading PCs"  can be as many as you may want or need, but it should be less than the full dimensionality of your space. Setting up some notation, if $\mathbf x$ is your test sample and $\mathbf U_p$ a matrix with $p$ leading principal axes in columns, then the reconstruction error is given by $$L = \|\mathbf x - \mathbf U_p^\vphantom{\top} \mathbf U_p^\top \mathbf x\|^2.$$

In the interest of the following section, let us transform this formula:

\begin{align}
L &= \|\mathbf x\|^2 - 2\mathbf x^\top \mathbf U_p^\vphantom{\top} \mathbf U_p^\top \mathbf x + \mathbf x^\top \mathbf U_p^\vphantom{\top} \mathbf U_p^\top \mathbf U_p^\vphantom{\top} \mathbf U_p^\top \mathbf x
\\&= \|\mathbf x\|^2 - \mathbf x^\top \mathbf U_p^\vphantom{\top} \mathbf U_p^\top \mathbf x
\\ &= \|\mathbf x\|^2 - \|\mathbf U_p^\top \mathbf x\|^2.
\end{align}

This is essentially Pythagoras theorem: squared length of $\mathbf x$ is equal to the sum of the squared length of its projection on the principal space and the
squared length of the reconstruction error (because they are orthogonal).

#### Kernel PCA

When we do kernel PCA $\left(\mathbf x \mapsto \phi(\mathbf x)\right)$, we cannot compute principal axes $\mathbf U$ because they often live in an infinite-dimensional space. Instead, we apply *kernel trick* and compute principal components directly, by eigen-decomposition of the kernel matrix $\mathbf K$: if its eigenvectors are $\mathbf V$ and eigenvalues are on the diagonal of $\mathbf S^2$, then kernel principal components (principal components in the target space) are given by $\mathbf S \mathbf V^\top$. Moreover, any new test sample $\mathbf x$ can be projected on the principal space via $\mathbf S^{-1} \mathbf V^\top \mathbf k$, where $\mathbf k$ is a column vector with coordinates $k_i = k(\mathbf x, \mathbf x_i)$ for all training samples $\mathbf x_i$. Here $k(\cdot, \cdot)=\langle \phi(\cdot), \phi(\cdot)\rangle$ is the kernel function. This you know.

Now consider the reconstruction error in the target space:

\begin{align}
\|\phi(\mathbf x) - \mathbf U_p^\vphantom{\top} \mathbf U_p^\top \phi(\mathbf x)\|^2 &= \|\phi(\mathbf x)\|^2 - \|\mathbf U_p^\top \phi(\mathbf x)\|^2
\\ &= k(\mathbf x, \mathbf x) - \|\mathbf S_p^{-1} \mathbf V_p^\top \mathbf k\|^2.
\end{align}

Voilà, this can be computed.

In the context of your question (comparing two sets of kPCA axes for one given $\mathbf x$) the first term is a constant and so the only relevant term is the second, which is simply the variance of the projection onto the first $p$ principal components. So you can take your test sample, project it on the first $p$ components, and look at the variance. The higher the variance, the better the fit.

Comment: Thanks! just to verify: $k(x,x)$ is the kernel of the new vector to itself (i.e. a matrix of size $n\times n$ if $n$ is the length of the vector)? and it is deducted a scalar value?

Comment: Edit: obviously it is a scalar, but the question remains. Won't this just be constant for any $x$?

Comment: @ido: yes, kernel scalar product of the test vector to itself (so a scalar, yes). For any given $\mathbf x$ it is a constant. Actually, it means that in the context of your question (comparing two sets of PCA axes for one $\mathbf x$) the only relevant term is the second, which is simply the variance of the projection onto the first $p$ principal components. Which means that you take your test sample, project on the first $p$ components, and look at the variance. The higher the variance -- the better the fit. Makes total sense, but I did not think about it when I started writing my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. I am trying a toy example, where I use kPCA but with linear kernel (i.e. normal PCA) and attempt to get zero error when computing with full dimensions and where the "new" sample is taken from the original data. Unfortunately, I cannot get zero error. To verify - according to your explanation - I should be able to, right?

Comment: Specifically, on the last equation in your answer - we have $k(x,x)=x'x$ (linear kernel), but on the other side we have $k^TVS^TSV^Tk$, and we will get the term $XX^T$ in the middle. How can this be zero? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for spotting a mistake! The projection formula in kPCA is not $\mathbf S \mathbf V^\top \mathbf k$, but $\mathbf S^{-1} \mathbf V^\top \mathbf k$. Indeed, if $\mathbf X=\mathbf U\mathbf S\mathbf V^\top$ (I assume that variables are in rows and samples in columns) and $\mathbf k = \mathbf X^\top \mathbf x$, then $\mathbf k = \mathbf V \mathbf S \mathbf U^\top \mathbf x$ and so $\mathbf U^\top \mathbf x = \mathbf S^{-1} \mathbf V^\top \mathbf k$. Now it should work out. I updated the answer.

Comment: It is probable to get zero eigenvalues, or otherwise very close. Will the formula be valid then? Sorry for all the scrutiny, but I would really like my toy example (at least) to work properly.
As far as I see, when (numerically) very small negative or positive eigenvalues are obtained, the reconstruction will have errors.

Comment: Okay, to answer myself - it works perfectly; if I just take a small epsilon instead of zeros in the eigenvalue diagonal, I get a very low error. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good point about zero eigenvalues (and no need to apologize for the scrutiny, I appreciate it!). As far as I can see, zero eigenvalues would mean that $n$ data points lie on a subspace with dimensionality smaller than $n$ (not very likely with non-trivial kernels, but will certainly happen with a linear kernel in a space with dimensionality $d<n$). I guess one can simply discard the corresponding eigenvectors and take only PCs corresponding to non-zero [above a small epsilon] eigenvalues. This should already lead to near-zero error. Your way is probably fine too.